# the cooling (temperature) of the refrigerator

Tags: word-choice

I am going to write down two similar sentences below.

(1) How do you increase the cooling (temperature) of the refrigerator?

(2) How do you change the cooling (temperature) of the refrigerator?

In both sentences, is it **redundant** to include "temperature"?

Comment: If you omit "temperature" in sentence 1, the reader will think that you actually want to make the temperature lower.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either are good enough although I am a non-native speaker but that's what comes to mind:

- How to adjust (*set*, *change*) the refridgerator temperature (*controls*, *settings*)?

You can also use the words **lower** and **raise**:

- How do you lower (*raise*) the temparature in the refrigerator or freezer?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the verb "cool"? Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary suggests: *The cylinder is cooled by a jet of water.*

"How do you cool the temperature of the refrigerator?"